# Tabularx undefined control sequence error with polyglossia Arabic and English language

Tags: tables, tabularx, polyglossia

I am receiving an undefined control sequence for tabularx, I found that adding the Arabic language causes the error, but I don't know how to fix it. My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial}
\setmainlanguage{english}
%\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{Calibri}
\newfontfamily\englishfonttt{Inconsolata}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll}
    2&2\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I am using XeLaTeX.

Comment: This is fixed in the next `memoir` release, ETA yet unknown, but should be out in time for TeXLive 2018

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a clash between `memoir`, `tabularx`, and `bidi`. `memoir` contains its own implementation of `tabularx` which is incompatible with how `bidi` tries to patch `tabularx`.

The solution is to start your file with:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\DisemulatePackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

Things will then compile correctly.